# Triggering multiple elements with one touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, touch-event, jquery-events

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/3743/

Javascript in question:

```
$('div').on('mouseenter touchstart touchenter', function(event) {

    console.log('Entered ' + $(this).attr('class') + ' by ' +
               event.type);

})
```

What I'm having trouble accomplishing:

- Trigger all 4 divs in one 'movement' on a touch device

Comment: What exactly do you mean by trigger all 4 divs in 1 movement?

Comment: I mean sequentially trigger an event in each div with one swipe. Similar to the console log for mousing over all 4 in turn. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Have a look at this and let me know if this is what you mean - http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/3744/

Comment: Not quite! I have a function I want to call every time a user enters a div, but they can enter the divs at will.